# AngularJS Doesn't Update Instantly When I push in Modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using angular ui for the modal, when I push, it enters to the array I specified but it doesn't update instantly like it should, I still have to refresh the page

```
<button class="btn btn-regular mustard-lighten-1 white-text" ng-click="showModal()"><span class="material-icons">add</span></button>

$scope.showModal = () => {
    let modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animated: true,
        templateUrl: 'pages/modals/add-modal.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })
} // show modal on the overview page

$scope.addRule = () => {

    $scope.rules.push({
        // properties inside here
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update 1 :** Try this.

```
$timeout(function () {
   $scope.rules.push({
      // properties inside here
   });
},1100);
```

Try this, This worked for me :

```
 $rootScope.$apply(function () {
   $scope.rules.push({
      // properties inside here
   });
 });
```

Comment: you mean insert another function inside my "addRule" function?

Comment: It throws an error "Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress"